# How to pass two parameters into lambda functions in map

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I wish to use `map` to do the following thing:

```
res = []
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [5, 0, 10]
for n, m in zip(arr1, arr2):
    res.append(n - 0.5 * m)
```

This is equivalent to do in list comp:

```
res = [n - 0.5 * m for n, m in zip(arr1 ,arr2)]
```

But it fails using `map`:

```
res = map(lambda x, y: x - 0.5 * y, zip(arr1, arr2)) 

TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Is there a neat way to do this using `map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You zipped the arr1 and arr2 into a single argument

```
>>> res = []
>>> arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> arr2 = [5, 0, 10]
>>> res = map(lambda x, y: x - 0.5 * y, arr1, arr2)
>>> res
[-1.5, 2.0, -2.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> map(lambda (x, y): x - 0.5 * y, zip(arr1, arr2)) 
[-1.5, 2.0, -2.0]
```

Like that you could take a tuple in lambda to fix it but I prefer what DTing suggested.

Comment: Alas, I get a syntax error when I try to provide a tuple to lambda as a means to having two named arguments instead of using tuple indexing of the zip expression.